# How to use reactiveValues instead of reactiveVal as a module parameter?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shinyjs

#### Working minmal example

I am trying to disable a module UI with the package `shinyjs`. From the main app I use a reactive paramater called `enabled`:

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# ____________________________________________
##########
# MODULE #
##########

subUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton(ns("click"), "CLICK!")
  )
}

subServer <- function(id, enabled) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(enabled))
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        if(enabled()) {
          enable("click")
        } else {
          disable("click")
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

# ____________________________________________
##############
# MAIN APP   #
##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("toggle", "Toggle"),
  subUI("sub")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  enabled <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  
  subServer("sub", enabled)
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, { enabled(! enabled()) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(
  launch.browser = TRUE
))
```

---

#### Issue

In my real app I got a lots of reactive values to deal with and I am using `reactiveValues()` instead of `reactiveVal()` but I do not manage to adapt the above example. I have tried:

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# ____________________________________________
##############
# SUB MODULE #
##############

subUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton(ns("click"), "CLICK!")
  )
}

subServer <- function(id, enabled) {
  # stopifnot(is.reactive(enabled))
  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        if(enabled) {
          enable("click")
        } else {
          disable("click")
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

# ____________________________________________
##############
# MAIN APP   #
##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("toggle", "Toggle"),
  subUI("sub")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactiveValues()
  r$enabled <- TRUE
  
  subServer("sub", r$enabled)
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, { r$enabled <- ! r$enabled })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(
  launch.browser = TRUE
))
```

---

NB: I had to comment out this line `# stopifnot(is.reactive(enabled))` in the submodule server which raises an error I cannot understand:

---

```
Error in r$enabled : 
  Can't access reactive value 'enabled' outside of reactive consumer.
```

---

I think it was the purpose of `is.reactive()` to deal with reactive value...

Comment: With regard to the error you can't understand... as the message states, you can only access a reactive inside a reactive consumer.  A reactive consumer is something like `observe`, `observeEvent` or `reactive`.  So, something like `observe({ stopifnot(is.reactive(enabled)) })` should work.  But there may be better ways to do this.

Comment: Where is `x()` defined in your (sub) module?

Comment: @Limey `x()` was a mistyping but I cannot agree with your first comment, as you can see it perfectly works in the first piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two example approaches.
The first one, simply wraps the reactiveValue in a reactive() so it is closely aligned with your original working design.
The second one, passes the entire reactiveValues object and does relevant test, and uses it in place, perhaps its what you were searching for, unclear which you would prefer.

**1)**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# ____________________________________________
##############
# SUB MODULE #
##############

subUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton(ns("click"), "CLICK!")
  )
}

subServer <- function(id, enabled) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(enabled))
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        if(enabled()) {
          enable("click")
        } else {
          disable("click")
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

# ____________________________________________
##############
# MAIN APP   #
##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("toggle", "Toggle"),
  subUI("sub")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactiveValues()
  r$enabled <- TRUE
  
  
  subServer("sub", reactive(r$enabled))
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    r$enabled <- !r$enabled
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(
  launch.browser = TRUE
))
```

**2)**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# ____________________________________________
##############
# SUB MODULE #
##############

subUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton(ns("click"), "CLICK!")
  )
}

subServer <- function(id, enabled_container) {
  stopifnot(is.reactivevalues(enabled_container))

  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        if(enabled_container$enabled) {
          enable("click")
        } else {
          disable("click")
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

# ____________________________________________
##############
# MAIN APP   #
##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("toggle", "Toggle"),
  subUI("sub")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  r <- reactiveValues()
  r$enabled <- TRUE
  
  
  subServer("sub", r )
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    r$enabled <- !r$enabled
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(
  launch.browser = TRUE
))
```